# Jquery xml parsing loops

Tags: jquery

Can anyone recommend the best way to do the following?

I need a loop that will loop through the first two xml items and do something with the contents, then a second loop that will loop through items 3 onwards and do something different?  How can I specify this?

Thanks for your help

Paul

Comment: Got any code to show us? A place to start?

Comment: What is the problem? Don't you know how to write loops in JavaScript? Do you even need a loop? Why not access these elements directly?

Comment: No sorry - just an xml feed parsed by jquery into a variable called XML, each story is within an item node, just dont know how to approach a loop to parse it all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the items as you would normall (using `$.parseXML()` and `$.each()`), but check for the index of the item you're looking at and perform the different actions there.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/lukemartin/RsXw9/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

http://api.jquery.com/each/