# Loop through XML Parser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, xml-parsing

I am developing an app, where on the click of a button, a list of the document information stored in an XML file is shown on screen in a `<ul>` tag. The current JavaScript in the function is;

```
    function viewXMLFiles() {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "TestInfo.xml", false);
        xmlhttp.send();

        xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

        document.getElementById("docname").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("document_name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("filetype").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("file_type")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("fileloc").innerHTML = pathToRoot + "/" + document.getElementById("docname").innerHTML;

        document.getElementById("docname1").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("document_name")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("filetype1").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("file_type")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("fileloc1").innerHTML = pathToRoot + "/" + document.getElementById("docname1").innerHTML;
    }
```

but i want to set it so that even if more file information is added, the function will display it too. i have already looked at [Jquery xml parsing loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447640/jquery-xml-parsing-loops) this question, but i couldn't get the function to work. Here's the XML file;

```
 <document_list>

<document>

    <document_name>Holidays.pdf</document_name><br />

    <file_type>.pdf</file_type> <br />

    <file_location>TEST</file_location> <br />

</document>

<document>

    <document_name>iPhone.jsNotes.docx</document_name><br />

    <file_type>.docx</file_type><br />

    <file_location>TEST</file_location><br />

</document>

 </document_list>
```

And this is the HTML i am using. There's a button and the `<ul>` tags i'm using;

```
<button onclick = "viewXMLFiles(); document.getElementById('showDocumentLink').style.display = 'block';">View Document Info</button><br>

    <div id = "doclist">
        <h2>Document 1;</h2>
        <label>Document Name;</label><br><span id = "docname"></span><br>
        <label>File Type</label><br><span id = "filetype"></span><br>
        <label>File Location</label><br><span id = "fileloc"></span><br>
    </div>

    <div id = "doclist">
        <h2>Document 2;</h2>
        <label>Document Name;</label><br><span id = "docname1"></span><br>
        <label>File Type</label><br><span id = "filetype1"></span><br>
        <label>File Location</label><br><span id = "fileloc1"></span><br>
    </div>
```

Can anyone help me put this into a loop? I have linked jQuery and jQTouch so i can use both of them.

Thank you so much in advance xx

Comment: `<div id = "doclist">` is not valid HTML; there should be no space around the `=`. Furthermore, an _id_ should be unique but the same value appears twice in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Irfan's answer as a base, to get the values into your labels add a counter, then just insert the values grabbed from the XML parsing loop into the corresponding span.

```
<script>
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "TestInfo.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();

    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    $xml = $( xmlDoc );
    var documents = $xml.find('document_list');

    var doccount = 0;

    //will be used to find the HTML elements
    var namelabel = "docname"; 
    var typelabel = "filetype"; 
    var locationlabel = "fileloc";

    documents.children('document').each(function() {
      var name = $(this).find('document_name').text();
      var file_type = $(this).find('file_type').text();
      var file_location = $(this).find('file_location').text();

      //after the first document we need to add the number to the span id
      if(doccount > 0){ 
         namelabel = "docname" + doccount;
         typelabel = "filetype" + doccount;
         locationlabel = "fileloc" + doccount;
      }

      //insert the XML values into the label
      $('span#'+namelabel).html(name);
      $('span#'+typelabel).html(file_type);
      $('span#'+locationlabel).html(file_location);  

      //increment the counter
      doccount++;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The strings built during the `if` statement were wrong... edited.

Comment: Your function is probably not being passed the XML file correctly. I've edited my answer to combine your old function and the new one. Use the `XMLHttpRequest` value instead of the JQuery parsed version.

Answer (score 2):

Use following loop code.

```
<script>
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc );
    var documents = $xml.find('document_list');

    documents.children('document').each(function() {
      var name = $(this).find('document_name').text();
      var file_type = $(this).find('file_type').text();
      var file_location = $(this).find('file_location').text();

      // now do whatever you like with above variable
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$(this)`, `$(this)`, `$(this)` ? `$` has a huge overhead, cache it - `var $this = $(this);`

Comment: when wrapping a single DOM element `$` has _some_ overhead, so indeed it should be cached, but it's not "huge".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a native JavaScript implementation so you can see how you'd do it that way and compare, etc.

```
function viewXMLFiles() {
    // var everything
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        xmlDoc,
        nodes, i, j, counter = -1, suffix,
        document_name, file_type, file_location;
    // request page
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "TestInfo.xml", false),
    xmlhttp.send();
    // false meant synchronous req. so can go straight to reading document
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    // loop over <document> nodes
    nodes = xmlDoc.childNodes; // shorthand
    j = nodes.length;
    for (i = 0; i < j; ++i) {
        if ('document' === nodes[i].tagName.toLowerCase()) {
            // nodes[i] is a <document>, increment counter
            ++counter;
            // get nodes of intrest
            document_name = nodes[i].getElementsByTagName("document_name")[0];
            file_type = nodes[i].getElementsByTagName("file_type")[0];
            file_location = nodes[i].getElementsByTagName("file_location")[0];

            // do what you want with these, e.g.
            suffix = counter || ''; // don't append a number for 0
            document.getElementById('docname'+suffix).textContent = document_name.textContent;
            document.getElementById('filetype'+suffix).textContent = file_type.textContent;
            document.getElementById('fileloc'+suffix).textContent = pathToRoot + "/" + file_location.textContent;
        }
    }
}
```

Furthermore, you should consider the validity of your HTML, as I mentioned in my comment;

- there should be no spaces around the equals sign of an attribute name/value pair, i.e. `<tag attrib="val"/>` **not** `<tag attrib = "val"/>`
- every *id* attribute should have a unique value, not shared with any other on the document, i.e. **not** `<tag id="shared"/><tag id="shared"/>`