# get XML node childs in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm looking to parse an XML file like this

```
<class>
    <subject>
        <knowledgeLevel> 1 </knowledgeLevel>
        <subjectName> Try1 </subjectName>
        <theory>
            <tutorial> Quickly Explain Try1 </tutorial>
            <full> Largely Explain Try1 </full>
        </theory>
        <example>
            <id> 1 </id>
            <code> some code </code>
            <level> easy </level>
        </example>
        <example>
            <id> 2 </id>
            <code> some code </code>
            <level> hard </level>
        </example>
    </subject>
</class>
```

considering that more than one subject will be present in the file in the end, how do I get the theory's and the example's subChilds to write an HTML table with Javascript?

Comment: See my answer at Loop through XML Parser?[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15612898/1058406

Comment: @Janinho67 look into [$.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) it will parse it into an array like structure then just literate and concatenate strings together till you can form an html [`table`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

Comment: @Janinho67: In what format do you have that XML file, as a plain text string? If it was loaded via XHR, it should be a DOM document already (and there's no need to *parse* it, only *traverse* it)

Comment: xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","subjects.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
                    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

Answer (score 0):

This simple piece of script should work for your purposes; it wraps the XML inside a temporary `<div>` element so that you can traverse it.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.innerHTML = xml;

function getChildElements(node, fn)
{
  [].forEach.call(node.childNodes, function(node) {
    if (node.nodeType == 1) {
      fn(node);
    }
  });
}

getChildElements(div.firstChild, function(subject) {
  getChildElements(subject, function(info) {
      console.log(info.tagName);
      console.log(info.textContent);
  });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/obutuj/2/)

Comment: No, don't try to load XML in a HTML document!

Comment: @Bergi Would you mind explaining this "dogma" you speak of? :)

Comment: I don't think a browser's HTML parser is well suited for XML (and I worry about standard-conformance, or unknown tags especially in older browsers). If it was HTML you tried to parse the `<div>` is fine, but why use it for XML when there is [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser)/[`xhr.responseXML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest)?

Comment: @Bergi Okay, I must admit I was not aware of `DOMParser` :)

Comment: @Bergi Though, is it expected that DOMParser doesn't exist in IE?

Comment: Oh, if you need to support IE then there's `new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")` for those who don't obey the standard :-)